# Magento Market place submit extension with licence

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, extensions, marketplace

> I have developed Magento extension that I want to upload on Magento
>   marketplace.
>
> I have gone through the process how it works explained Here: 
>   https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-connect-moving-marketplace
>
> Does marketplace allow to submit domain-specific modules?  I want to
>   upload domain specific license key for my extension which I can do
>   from my side but if I want to submit the same extension to marketplace
>   then Magento will consider my extension?
>
> Do they allow to submit the Domain-based license extension?
>
> I have developed API based extension for which I need to set domain
>   access in my API. if I remove domain specific then how can I be sure
>   who has purchased my extension and to which domain I need to give
>   access?
>
> Need suggestion what could be the solution for it.

Comment: @umesh  Can you answer it?

Comment: Great question. You can ask this question to marketplace support by this email `marketplace@magento.com`

Comment: @PrincePatel  yes i can get the confirmation from the market place support but i expect quickest reply so i thought this is the best place.  

it could help to other as well.

Comment: @Teja bhagavan  can you answer it?

Comment: @jack magento marketplace does not allow domain specific license for extension because team need to some testing and check  functionality for extension my be that's  why.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Marketplace have they own license mechanism for paid extensions, it all done by Composer authorisation Public Access Key and Private Access Keys. At this moment there is no domain control, so if someone purchase your extension - he can use it on multiple domains.

More details about install extension from Marketplace - http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html